# Do I always fetch into a NSArray from CoreData?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I am fetching something from `CoreData` where I expect `1 result` or `nil`.

Currently I set the fetch into a `NSArray` and I attempted as it stand to fetch into a `IconRoutine*` object but the `[context executeFetchRequest:fetchIcon error:&error];` needs to fetch into an array, thus resulting in a crash when I tried that.

I guess what I wonder is if I can maybe in another way to fetch into a `entity object` so that I dont need the `if ( [Icon count] !=0 )` to check for a `nil` and I can just return whatever is fetched and deal with the `nil entity` in another method.

or maybe just a more efficient way (if there is one) to deal with results that you expect `1` or `nil`.

```
- (IconRoutine *) getIconRoutine {

    NSFetchRequest *fetchIcon = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entityItem = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"IconRoutine" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchIcon setEntity:entityItem];

    [fetchIcon setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"User",@"Routine", nil]];

    [fetchIcon setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(routine.routineName == %@) AND (user.email LIKE %@) AND (author LIKE %@)",_routineNameInput.text,_appDelegate.currentUser,_routineAuthor]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray* Icon = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchIcon error:&error];

    if ( [Icon count] !=0 ) {
        return Icon[0];
    }
    return NO;    
}
```

Comment: That's just the way Core Data works I'm afraid. You always fetch into an array.

Comment: And note that a return value `nil` means "error", whereas an empty array means "no results".

Comment: Could you explain what you want to achieve? `getIconRoutine` returns a `IconRoutine` and not a boolean. Thanks.

Comment: And what abut the crash? Add some details...

Comment: @flexaddicted he wants to return the IconRoutine object if it exists otherwise return nil (he is just using NO instead of nil I believe).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option. Not necessarily the solution you are looking for but one that may help:

```
- (IconRoutine *) getIconRoutine {

    NSFetchRequest *fetchIcon = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entityItem = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"IconRoutine" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchIcon setEntity:entityItem];

    [fetchIcon setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"User",@"Routine", nil]];

    [fetchIcon setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(routine.routineName == %@) AND (user.email LIKE %@) AND (author LIKE %@)",_routineNameInput.text,_appDelegate.currentUser,_routineAuthor]];

    return [context executeFetchRequest:fetchIcon error:nil].lastObject;    
}
```

This obviously only works if you don't care about the error message. `lastObject` will return nil if either the `NSArray` is nil or if the array is empty (so never an `indexOutOfBoundsException`)! Otherwise, it will return the last object, and if there is only one it will just return that.

If you do care about the error you could just simply do:

```
- (IconRoutine *) getIconRoutine {

    // fetch code from above
    // ..    

    NSError *fetchError
    IconRoutine *result = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchIcon error:&fetchError].lastObject;

    if (fetchError) {
        // handle the error
    }

    // return whatever result is anyway because if there was an error it would already be nil, and if not then it is the object you are looking for
    return result;
}
```

Hope this helps!